# Android Listview crash

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple app that displays the array elements inside a list view. But when I run the project, my application crashes on this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

here is the MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.example.asus.listview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ListView list;
    String [] days = {"sunday","monday","tuesday","wendsday","tursday","friday","saturday"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setThisList();
    }
    public void setThisList () {
        //initializing the list view
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        // read the array and select the view
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,days);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="96dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here I include the error log:

[image]

UPDATE:
I added this line "vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true" to defaultConfig and now I get this new error:
[image]

My build.gradle file now looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        applicationId "com.example.asus.listview"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha2'
}
```

Comment: show complete logcat... it is uncomplete...

Comment: Post your `Build.Gradle` file.

Comment: Add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`  inside `defaultConfig` of `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Shree Krishna, I did what you said and I'm getting a new error

Comment: @zamzam downgrade your support design library like use `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` Or another if works. Try that. And also remove the previous `useSupportLibrary` statement.

Comment: @Shree Krishna, did not work

Answer (score 0):

In your exception, I see that the exception is thrown when your app tries to get the drawable to be displayed in your Toolbar. It doesn't seem to be a problem with the ListView (at least the app doesn't complain about it for the time being). Are you setting any specific backgrounds or resources to your Toolbar through some styling/theming?

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace shows that it's not related with your code, but the drawable used in the Toolbar. It seems to be dus to a missing support library in the gradle configuration.

Check if you have included the right support library in your `build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Comment: in AndroidStudio within the Project view, it is the build.gradle of your application module

Comment: I did what you said and I get this new error (I updated the question)

Comment: you just need to add this line to your default config `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`. The `...` were there to symbolize the previous content of the file.